# table colspan in emails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm trying to get the image to align to the right and the rows with text on the left in my table using colspan. This method usually works when the image is on the left but now I want it on the right it wont work. Please keep in mind this is for outlook email so you cannot use floats, align="right" etc.

heres my code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="580" style="border: 1px solid;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 10px;">sdfsdfsdfsdfdsdfhhhhhhhhlklkjlkj</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>sdfsdf</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3" ><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/b083c967cd22e35ab4ce75e7a/images/e3c991a6-22c4-4ee2-a08d-7d23e30f8c29.png" alt="" width="400"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yk3fanoq/1/

Comment: Try the link and see if you are looking for something similar.
https://jsfiddle.net/reddysridhar53/a8pne561

Comment: I would suggest not using colspans. Some email clients don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the text and image in two columns (td)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          sdfsdfsdfsdfdsdfhhhhhhhhlklk
          sdfsdf
        </td>  
        <td rowspan="3" align="right">
          <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/b083c967cd22e35ab4ce75e7a/images/e3c991a6-22c4-4ee2-a08d-7d23e30f8c29.png" alt="" width="400">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```